# Android Studio vs Visual Studio ( Cross Platform Native Mobile App Development )

Tags: c#, android, ios, visual-studio, cross-platform

I am a beginner. I am learning to develop Android Apps. What are the differences between Android Studio and Visual Studio? I have checked the Visual Studio website recently. I have seen this sentence

> "Hybrid apps with JavaScript and Native apps with C#".

What does this mean? Does it mean that we can create native mobile apps in Visual Studio with full control like Android Studio? What are the pros and cons between them, and Which is the correct path for beginners?

I also have the idea to learn to develop iOS Apps as well. Can I learn C# and use Visual Studio if the Android Studio and Visual Studio has same features and the performance of the Developed Apps are same?

Comment: This question would be better asked on Meta Stack as it does not ask a programming question and could attract opinion based answers ;-)

Comment: @AppDevGuy, please, no, Meta Stack is for discussing SO itself, not for "all questions that don't fit in SO". [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) or [Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/) would be much better guesses.

Comment: @2Dee I agree that is what is for, however since Meta Caters to all things surrounding programming, I naturally lean towards the notion that discussing opinion based topics relevant to learning programming, Meta would be a more suitable place. Happy to be wrong. Merely my own opinion.

Comment: @AppDevGuy no problem. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) ;)

Comment: As a beginner: stick to AndroidStudio - it is the gold standard when it comes to Android development. If you're interested in developing multi platform apps try the ionic framework (hybrid apps written in HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript).

Comment: @2Dee  Sorry for poor English. In the Visual Studio Website. It says we can create native apps with C# with the use of Visual Studio 2015.Does that mean that we can create native apps same as the Apps from Android Studio? If yes, What are differences between the Android Studio native apps and Visual studio native apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might be confused. Microsoft recently partnered with Xamarin. It gave Visual Studio the capabilities to create iOS, Android, and Windows applications (with a price, using C#).

Android Studio (if i am not mistaken) is used to create native Android applications using Java.

If you are interested in learning to develop a **Cross Platform** application using **C#**, then check out Xamarin.

A simple google search "hybrid vs native" app will give you the pros and cons.

Check this link for more information - [Xamarin Blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/microsoft-and-xamarin-expand-global-partnership/)

Comment: "with a price, using C#" Thats called an advantage!

Comment: wait, how are java applications native? or is android using some kind of AOT compilation?