# Can I use C# in Android Studio?

Tags: java, c#, android

I'd like to develop an application in Android Studio.
I don't know Java.
I don't want Xamarin.
Is there a way to use C# in Android Studio?

Comment: Xamarin is how you use C# for Android. Why don't you want to use it? From what I can tell, though, C# and Java are very similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio vs Visual Studio ( Cross Platform Native Mobile App Development )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474352/android-studio-vs-visual-studio-cross-platform-native-mobile-app-development)

Comment: No, C# is not officially supported by Google, you can develop in C++, Java, Kotlin and Dart.

Comment: You dont know java but if you know C# they syntax is *mostly the same*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a way to use c# in android studio.

No, sorry.

> I don't want xamarin.

Then you will not be able to build in C#, AFAIK.

> I don't know java

If you wish to use Android Studio, you will need to learn Java and/or Kotlin.

Answer (score 6):

even tho you cannot use c# on android studio, **it is possible using [visual studio.](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/)** 
(to develop apps for android)
after you download visual studio (if you haven't already) a window similar to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/media/vs-2019/vs-installer-workloads.png?view=vs-2019) will pop up. you need to choose the option: ["mobile development with .net"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgP7H.png)
and then click download / modify. if you already have visual studio installed, go to  [create new project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/media/vs-2019/start-window-create-new-project.png?view=vs-2019)>> (scroll down) click on: "not finding what you are looking for?" and then the modify menu will open

- I know you are looking for a c# code in android studio, but because

> If you wish to use Android Studio, you will need to learn Java and/or Kotlin.

this is the best alternative.

Comment: If you DO follow this approach (!!) then you will stuck in 'a maze of twisty passages all alike' which is otherwise known as 'Xamarin' and which has absolutely no future as of Nov 2022  Moreover - you will *never* achieve anything like a mobile app which can run on UWP, Android and IOS despite decades of trying  You have been warned!

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin is C#s solution to android development. You cannot use C# in Android Studio. However, Java is VERY similar to C#. I was thrust into a Java Android development project at work without having ANY prior knowledge in Java, but knowledge and experience in C#. Took just a couple of days to get used to it. Bit the bullet and go for it. At the very least, you'll then be able to say that you know 2 programming languages (C# and Java).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use c# in Android Studio. You could use Xamarin. This tool is integrated with Visual Studio 2022. You can find it at this link: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/xamarin